# how to verify email and mobile number using firebase database in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase database, but I am able to perform CRUD type operation with Firebase. And now I want to know how an email or a mobile could be verify by using Firebase database.

Comment: Have you seen https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-validation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess its not possible to verify email or phone number using firebase database.

You need to do it on your own mechanism, but you can also use [firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/). You need to keep track by your own logic that user is verified or not before completing authentication service. And only after getting success result from authentication change the status.

Here is the link for [email verification.](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/02/email-verification-in-firebase-auth.html)

And this is for [phone number verification.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

Answer (score 0):

Email verification for android is now available in Firebase. Check this:https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#9.6